# Installing package Golearn

Tags: linux, bash, go, package

I'm try to install the package Golearn, following [these](https://github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn/wiki/Installation) instructions.

After running in the terminal

```
go get -t -u -v github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn
```

I tried to run (as required):

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn
```

However bash doesn't find this directory. What should I do?
(I'm using linux)

Comment: Those instructions appear to be outdated, and assume that you're using GOPATH which is now obsolete.

Comment: Thanks @Flimzy! How should I do?

Comment: Clone the repo anywhere you want, cd into it and use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> install the package Golearn

Example build, in /home/name/tmp/

```
git clone https://github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn.git
cd golearn/

        ## Completing the installation
        ## Run the following to complete installation
go get -t -u -v ./...
```

Using : Please (also) read the text file README.md .

Answer (score 1):

I did the following and worked:

```
go get -t -u -v github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn
```

> go: downloading github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn v0.0.0-20221228163002-74ae077eafb2
> go: added github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn v0.0.0-20221228163002-74ae077eafb

```
go env GOPATH
```

> /Users/<my_username>/go

```
cd /Users/<my_username>/go/pkg/mod/github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn@v0.0.0-20221228163002-74ae077eafb2

sudo go get -t -u -v ./...
```

Answer (score -1):

The instruction of golearn maybe some outdated, you can follow my process:

1. `cd` into a empty folder, like `/home/your/code/my_golearn`, all commands below should be run at this floder
2. run `go mod init my_golearn` to init a go project, you will get a `go.mod` file
3. create a `main.go` file and fill it with code from https://github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn#getting-started
4. run `go get github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn`
5. run `go mod download` to get all dependencies
6. run `go get github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn/knn`, it's strange, but it doesn't work if this command miss, I think maybe the developer of golearn has some misuse of go mod
7. run `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sjwhitworth/golearn/master/examples/datasets/iris.csv -P datasets` to get dataset you need
8. run `go run ./main.go`, you will get result same as https://github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn#getting-started

If you are not familiar with how to install dependency in a modern go project, it's better for you to go through https://go.dev/blog/using-go-modules